# Why is the boolean modifier creating a glitchy mesh instead of cutting into the object?

Tags: modifiers

I'm modeling a city and wanted to create a river with help of boolean modifier. I've checked doubles and normals, so I don't know what the problem is when I'm adding a boolean modifier. You can see what's happening and nothing is happening to plane, just glitchy bugs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How much this plane is subdivided?

Comment: I tried both. Non-subdivided and subdivided few or less times. The same glitchy thing. As i said thought that  it is something with normals or doubles. But no.

Comment: Please upload blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ I'll give it a look.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1891" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1891/)

Comment: I can't find what's wrong with those meshes. I've checked non manifold, internal faces, loosed ends, normals, doubles and everything seems ok, but it won't work. So here it is modified blend file with new plane and new river: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1894/ to check setup.

Comment: The problem with the Boolean is [non-manifold geometry](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry). In this case, infinitely flat object which is "Plane". Extrude it at least a bit and the problem will go away.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cut something into an object using boolean, the modifier has to be set on the mesh that you want to edit. Not on the stencil object. You also may change the visibility of the scencil object from textured to bounds.

It then should just look like this [image]

Also i recommend using the BoolTool Addon. It is far more user friendly.